# Accessing JSON from within a spring MappingJacksonJsonView

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jackson

Below is how I'm trying to access the json, do I need to change the dataType wthin jQuery ?

```
service : 
    @RequestMapping("VIEW")
    @ResourceMapping("myUrl")
    public MappingJacksonJsonView savePortletData() {

        jsonString = outStream.toString();      
        argMap.addAttribute("portletDataResponseJson", "{\"test\": \"tester2\"}");

        return new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        }
        }

jquery:  
        $.ajax({
        url: "myUrl",       
        type: 'post',
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(jsonResponse) {  
        console.log('JSON IS '+jsonResponse;
        },
        });
```

Comment: you want to access json in the controller ?here is same question being asked.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760853/spring-controller-json-receive-json-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we are using with @ResponseBody object (to be converted to json)

```
public @ResponseBody PortletData savePortletData(){
}
```

so you dont need to create separate view, spring will detect json as request and will automatically apply message converter.

Comment: Can the object PortletData be a pojo or does it need anotations so it can be converted ?

Comment: it can be any Pojo, jackson will do conversion based on properties.